# Use Sass with antdesign in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sass, antd

I am trying to use [antdesign](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) and Sass in my project. I found this [article](https://intoli.com/blog/antd-scss-theme-plugin/) which uses [antd-scss-theme-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-scss-theme-plugin) but this requires to eject the react project so I am wondering if there are any **updated** ways to use Sass with antdesign in react project.

Comment: There is [updated official antd docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app)  it uses craco so you don't need to eject the react app to modify theme etc.